# Extract values from multidimensional array using key value

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I wonder if someone can help me extract values from an array by key value rather than array number.

```
$json = json_decode($stock, true);
print_r($json);
$sims = $json['stock'][1]['sims'];

foreach ($sims as $sim)
{
    echo nl2br($sim . "\n");
}
```

The output from `print_r($json)` is:

```
Array ( [stock] => Array (
[0] => Array
( [operator] => ECL [sims] => Array
( [0] => 8944122616994 [1] => 89650264517182 [2] => 894412265075 [3] => 894412 ) )
[1] => Array
( [operator] => JT [sims] => Array
( [0] => 89445023065 [1] => 894156673081 [2] => 8944501 [3] => 89445027 ) ) ) )
```

It appears that sometimes the data I want is not in array number 1 hence I would like to extract it based on `"[operator] => JT"` I've been trying various ideas but it never seems to work.

Comment: This is a bit unclear - what is the output you're trying to get?

Comment: Could you maybe give us your JSON string and a clear example of what you're trying to extract from it?

Comment: Whoever downvoted its a very good question. Please add your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplice it by using [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

This will give you the multidimensional array key

```
$key = array_search("JT", array_column($json['stock'], 'operator'));
```

Then you can do

```
$sims = $json['stock'][$key]['sims'];
print_r($sims) //this will print desired array
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$json = json_decode($stock, true);

foreach($json["stock"] as $arr){
    echo $arr["operator"]."\n";
    foreach($arr["sims"] as $sim){
        echo $sim."\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

This would output (for example):

> ECL
>   8944122616994
>   89650264517182
>   894412265075
>   894412
>
> JT
>   89445023065
>   894156673081
>   8944501
>   89445027

Answer (score 0):

Write a function like this:

```php
function getSims(array $array) {
    $sims = [];

    foreach ($array as $data) {
        if ($data['operator'] == 'JT') {
            return $data['sims'];
        }
    }
    // here you could also throw an exception or return something else
    return [];
}
```

and use it like this:

```php
$json = json_decode($stock, true);
$sims = getSims($json['stock']);
```